# How to get an element/s containing specified text using Xpath on Jupyter Notebook (Python)?

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, xpath, jupyter-notebook

I need help with the following task please:
For instance this is part of the HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee, sugar bla bla bla ... milk.</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>milk</li>
  <li>123   @"£ sdfa  milk</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>1 2 milk 3 5...</li>
</ul>
```

I need to scrape all `<li>` elements which contain the word `milk` regardless of casing, other words etc.

I tried:

```
    from lxml import html
    import requests
    page = requests.get('WEB-ADDRESS.html')
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
    target = tree.xpath('//li[contains(text(),"milk")]')
```

Also tried:

```
   target3 = tree.xpath('//reflist[. = "milk"]')
```

But they both return empty - `[]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first solution does work. So you may need to double check the content in your `page.content`.

```py
from lxml import html
#import requests

content = """
<div>
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee, sugar bla bla bla ... milk.</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>milk</li>
      <li>123   @"£ sdfa  milk</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>1 2 milk 3 5...</li>
    </ul>
</div>
"""


tree = html.fromstring(content)

nodes = tree.xpath('//li[contains(text(), "milk")]')
for node in nodes:
    print(node.text)
```

```
Coffee, sugar bla bla bla ... milk.
milk
123   @"£ sdfa  milk
1 2 milk 3 5...
```

Comment: Thank you loads @Lavande I am just new to Python and did not know I should use 'print(node.text)' to actually see the results. I was trying just 'print' .

Comment: Now I need to concatenate all nodes in a .csv file so I can analyze it further as a table.